# Get amount of seconds from a formatted time string

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How to convert a time string like `1m15s` to `75s`, `75` or `75000` ideally using `momentjs`.

---

---

I attempted to parse that string using `new Date('1m1s')` but it gives `Invalid Date`.

I don't want to resort to regex:

```js
const second = (function () {
    const countdownStep = '1h1m1s'.match(
        /(?:(?<h>\d{0,2})h)?(?:(?<m>\d{0,2})m)?(?:(?<s>\d{0,2})s)?/i
    );
    return (
        (countdownStep.groups.h
            ? parseInt(countdownStep.groups.h) * 3600
            : 0) +
        (countdownStep.groups.m
            ? parseInt(countdownStep.groups.m) * 60
            : 0) +
        (countdownStep.groups.s ? parseInt(countdownStep.groups.s) : 0)
    );
})();
```

Comment: *"I don't want to resort to regex"*: why not? It is the most natural approach in vanilla JS.

Comment: *"I attempted to parse that string using `new Date('1m1s')`"*: of course, the documentation says the string should be IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps, or strings in a version of ISO8601. So this format will not be recognised, nor does it represent a date, but a time *span*.

Comment: @trincot I updated my full regex approach, It works fine but it looks like an ugly block of code and I feel that there might be another way using a JS time library in one or two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the duration interface of momentjs:

```js
let s = '1m15s';

// convert to duration format and pass to momentjs
let secs = moment.duration('PT' + s.toUpperCase()).as("seconds");

console.log("seconds: ", secs);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Without library, it could be:

```js
const unit = { s: 1, m: 60, h: 60*60 };
let s = '1m15s';
let secs = s.toLowerCase().match(/\d+./g)
            .reduce((acc, p) => acc + parseInt(p) * unit[p.at(-1)], 0);
console.log("seconds: ", secs);
```

Comment: So that *time span* is close to be considered as a duration in momentjs, right ? what does PT stand for ?

Comment: [P]eriod (which can be followed by Y, M, and D parts), and [T]ime. See also [Wikipedia on ISO8601 - Time Intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals)

Comment: See also [Wikipedia on ISO8601 - Durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)

Comment: Added a vanilla solution, with a short regex.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, is it helpful to you

```js
let d = '1H1s';
d = d.toLowerCase();
let sec = 0;
if(d.indexOf('h') > -1) {
    if (d.indexOf('m') == -1) {
        d = d.substring(0, d.indexOf('h') + 1) +"0m"+d.substring(d.indexOf('h') + 1);
    }
}
let newDs = d.replace('h',':').replace('m',':').replace('s','').split(':');
newDs.forEach((v, i) => sec += Math.pow(60, (newDs.length - i - 1)) * v);
console.log(sec);
```

Comment: That would fail with `1h1s`

Comment: right, I didn't check this case, I will try to modify it

Comment: Hi @medilies  I have modified the code `added the 1h1s condition`

Comment: Well fixed, I tried many combination and found 0 exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using plain js:

```js
const getSecondsFromString = (str) => {
  const hourIndex = str.indexOf("h")
  const minuteIndex = str.indexOf("m")
  const secondIndex = str.indexOf("s")
  let hours = 0
  let minutes = 0
  let seconds = 0

  if (hourIndex !== -1) {
    hours = Number(str.substring(0, hourIndex))
  }

  if (minuteIndex !== -1) {
    if (hourIndex !== -1) {
      minutes = Number(str.substring(hourIndex + 1, minuteIndex))
    } else {
      minutes = Number(str.substring(0, minuteIndex))
    }
  }

  if (secondIndex !== -1) {
    if (minuteIndex !== -1) {
      seconds = Number(str.substring(minuteIndex + 1, secondIndex))
    } else if (hourIndex !== -1) {
      seconds = Number(str.substring(hourIndex + 1, secondIndex))
    } else {
      seconds = Number(str.substring(0, secondIndex))
    }
  }

  return hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds
}
```

Comment: Consider doing `str.toLowerCase()` to allow strings like `1H1M1S`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach without substring/replace, in O(n);

```js
const getSecondsFromTimeString = (timeString) => {
    let numberBeforeNextChar = 0;
    let seconds = 0;
  
    const symbolToSecondMap = {
        "s" : 1,
        "m" : 60,
        "h" : 60*60,
        "d" : 60*60*24
    };
  
    for (let i = 0; i < timeString.length; i++) {
        let char = timeString.charAt(i);
        
        if((+ char) <= 9  && (+ char) >= 0 ){
            numberBeforeNextChar = (numberBeforeNextChar * 10) + parseInt(char);
            continue;
        }
    
        if(char.toLowerCase() == char.toUpperCase()){
            throw "Non alphanumeric symbol encountered";
        }

        if(symbolToSecondMap[char] === undefined){
            throw "Invalid date alphabet encountered";
        }
        
        seconds = seconds + (numberBeforeNextChar * symbolToSecondMap[char]);
        numberBeforeNextChar = 0;
    
  }
  
  return seconds;
} 



console.log(getSecondsFromTimeString('1s'))
console.log(getSecondsFromTimeString('10s'))
console.log(getSecondsFromTimeString('1s4m10d3h'))
console.log(getSecondsFromTimeString('1s4m03h1h'))
console.log(getSecondsFromTimeString('10d'))
```

Comment: Great solution, just consider doing `timeString.toLowerCase()` to allow uppercase time symbols